# Keep wordpress basic permalink preferences

Tags: permalinks

Im having trouble keeping wp basic permalink preferences, for my custom post type.
When I select the the basic permalink option that should be /?p=123?, it returns news=test-2.

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_news');
function my_custom_news()
{
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('お知らせ・コラム', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('news', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('新しくお知らせ・コラムを書く', 'news'),
    'add_new_item' => __('お知らせ・コラム記事を書く'),
    'edit_item' => __('お知らせ・コラム記事を編集'),
    'new_item' => __('新しいお知らせ・コラム記事'),
    'view_item' => __('お知らせ・コラム記事を見る'),
    'search_staff' => __('お知らせ・コラム記事を探す'),
    'not_found' =>  __('お知らせ・コラム記事はありません'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('ゴミ箱にお知らせ・コラム記事はありません'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
      "slug" => "news",
      "with_front" => false
    ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','revisions'),
    'has_archive' => true
  );
  register_post_type('news',$args);
}

/** ---- お知らせ・コラムタクソノミー追加 ---- **/
add_action ('init','create_newscat_taxonomy','0');
function create_newscat_taxonomy () {
    $taxonomylabels = array(
    'name' => _x('カテゴリー','post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('カテゴリー','post type singular name'),
    'search_items' => __('カテゴリー'),
    'all_items' => __('お知らせカテゴリー'),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Cat' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Cat:' ),
    'edit_item' => __('お知らせカテゴリーを編集'),
    'add_new_item' => __('お知らせカテゴリーを書く'),
    'menu_name' => __( 'お知らせカテゴリー' ),
    );
    $args = array(
    'labels' => $taxonomylabels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'newscat' )
    );
    register_taxonomy('newscat','news',$args);

    
    }
```

Comment: If you *do not* want to enable "pretty URLs" for your post type, then set the `rewrite` arg to `false`.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work.

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted to say is, you would want to use the [`post_type_link` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) to change your CPT's permalink URL, and use `?p=<post ID>&post_type=news` in the URL. But yes, the `&post_type=news` is needed and without it, WordPress would use the wrong post type (which is `post`). So is it a must for you to use *just* `?p=<post ID>` ?